# Azure Application connect to OneDrive Authentication Issue

Tags: python, azure, authentication

I need to programmatically connect to onedrive and download some files. I am using the following code which works fine. However, when another user of my Tenant tries it, he gets a message that he *must use MFA*. Could this be because I am a user administrator and he is not? or is this an issue with the permissions of the application I have registered? MFA cannot be touched.

```
import logging
import requests
import json
import msal
import requests

CLIENT_ID = ''
TENANT_ID = ''
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}'.format(TENANT_ID)
RESOURCE_URL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
API_VERSION = 'v1.0'
USERNAME = '' #Office365 user's account username
PASSWORD = ''
SCOPES = ['Sites.ReadWrite.All','Files.ReadWrite.All'] # Add other scopes/permissions as needed.
    #Creating a public client app, Aquire a access token for the user and set the header for API calls
cognos_to_onedrive = msal.PublicClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY_URL)
token = cognos_to_onedrive.acquire_token_by_username_password(USERNAME,PASSWORD,SCOPES)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token['access_token'])}
r = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{drive_id}/root:/DropFileOut', headers=headers).json()
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, somehow the MFA was disabled for my ID. The solution would be to add the user to the MFA Policy exceptions, in this case.